# Using Javascript and Regex to replace HTML Characters

Tags: javascript, html, regex, escaping

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have a need within an application to remove all HTML Characters and replace them with their HTML number equivalent.

For example:

```
‡, •, -, ‰, € and ™
```

Become:

```
&#8225;, &#8226;, &#45;, &#8240;, &#8364; and &#8482;
```

There are lot's of questions currently out there, but these do it the other way round.

I have all of the chars I want to convert in a JSON object (this is just a snapsshot of a much larger list, just to prove my JSON is good):

```
{"ch":"‘","sub":"&#8216;"},
{"ch":"’","sub":"&#8217;"},
{"ch":"‚","sub":"&#8218;"},
{"ch":"“","sub":"&#8220;"},
{"ch":"”","sub":"&#8221;"},
{"ch":"„","sub":"&#8222;"},
{"ch":"†","sub":"&#8224;"},
{"ch":"‡","sub":"&#8225;"},
{"ch":"•","sub":"&#8226;"},
...
```

And I currently loop through (using Prototype here) and attempt to replace them:

```
oJSONItems.each(function(o){
    var oRG = new RegExp(o.ch,'g');
    oText = oText.replace(oRG,o.sub);
});
```

Some are being replaced, but some are not...

```
‡
•
&#45;
‰
€
™
```

More than anything I need to know why chars like **™** are failing to be converted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than code for specific entities, how about one that replaces *anything* outside the original 7 bit ASCII range:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\011\012\015\040-\177]/g, function(x) {
    return '&#' + x.charCodeAt(0) + ';'
})
```

(The regexp matches anything that's not white space or a "normal" ASCII character)

Alternatively, write your map so that the *keys* are the characters you want to replace, and the values are the entities:

```
var map = { '£' : '&pound;' }

str = str.replace(/./g, function(x) {
    return (x in map) ? map[x] : x;
});
```

Note that both versions only make the regexp call *once*, rather than once for each possible entity in your set.  This should make the code somewhat faster than your loop-based method.

Comment: @Qtax it works ok for the 16 bit Unicode set - probably not for the extended ones.